# Login/Register in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, user-controls

Im starting to learn RoR and i want to make my personal blog in this language. I usually code a couple of prototypes on top of whatever im doing in my blog. So i would like people to be able to log in, and register with their openID. So i was about to jump to the coding  place when i realized the concept of gems and all that stuff is giving you tools for this kind of things.

So is there some kind of package to manage users, profiles and openId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise you to look at [bort](http://jimneath.org/bort/) as a complete RoR skeletton app with RESTful auth builtin, one of its fork [here](http://matthall.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/a-bort-fork-rails-base-application/) or at [AuthLogic](http://www.railsinside.com/plugins/145-authlogic-another-take-on-rails-authentication.html) a less intrusive auth solution for Rails (and Merb and some others).

Answer (score 3):

check out technoweeni's restful-authentication plugin

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the bort skeleton app.  It has restful auth and openid authentication already setup among other things.

Railscasts also has a number of screencasts about setting up authentication, restful authentication and OpenID.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you want to be aware of to avoid hours of headache: the Ruby OpenID [library](http://openidenabled.com/ruby-openid/) changed substantially with OpenID 2.0, so if you're using a plugin or example code from a blog, be sure you're using the version of OpenID to which it corresponds.

There are several plugins; one with lot of activity is [`open_id_authentication`](http://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication/network).

Dan Webb has a good [guide](http://www.danwebb.net/2007/2/27/the-no-shit-guide-to-supporting-openid-in-your-applications) to OpenID authentication in Rails that walks you through writing the actual code, but note that, at least last I checked, it hadn't been updated for OpenID 2.0.